# Can "allow for" be rewritten to "allow that "?

Tags: idioms

> Get started early to allow for possible problems.

I am trying to rewrite this by changing the noun "possible problems" to a sentence. My example is as follows:

> Get started early to allow that problems may occur.

Is "allow that" correct?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean when you write "changing the noun 'possible problems' to a sentence".  Do you mean you want to change it into a *that*-clause?

Comment: Yes. I would like to use that-clause .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**allow for** and **allow that...** mean different things, and in your scenario,  **allow for** is the right one.

> They left early to allow for traffic.

They left early *in case* they should encounter heavy traffic along the way.

**allow *for*** wants a nominal complement. We can make **possibility** that complement and in turn complement it with a *that*-clause:

> They left early to allow for the possibility that they would encounter
>   heavy traffic.

We can complement **allow** with a *that*-clause:

> I will allow that you have made a good point about the questionable
>   benefits of ethanol.

I will *concede* that you have made a good point.

We can also make a noun or pronoun the indirect object of **allow** and a noun its direct object:

> They left early to allow {themselves} <sup>io</sup> {extra time} <sup>do</sup>, in case there was heavy traffic along the way.

They left early to *give* themselves extra time.

Answer (score 1):

> > Get started early to allow that problems may occur.
>
> Is "allow that" correct?

No.

*Allow* has a number of senses. Only one of these licenses a 'content clause' complement (a finite clause optionally introduced by *that*). That is the colloquial sense (now fairly rare) "acknowledge, admit, claim", which is not the sense employed in your original sentence.

To *allow **for** X* is an idiom meaning to "anticipate"—to include in your plans the possibility of *X* happening and prevent *X* from creating unwanted results. The ***for*** is essential to its meaning.

Comment: How about "allow for the situation that/where problems may occur"

Comment: @rama9 That's fine, but unnecessarily wordy. And it doesn't mean quite the same thing: the original anticipates problems, your rewrite anticipates situations.